# Accessing C++ template types to use as further types for templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

I have following classes:

```
template<class PhysicalType, class LogicalType, int offset>
class Cluster
{
public:
    typedef PhysicalType PhyType;
    typedef LogicalType LogType;
};

template<class PhysicalType>
class Axis 
{

};
```

How can I create a 3rd class that uses the first one as a template class and further use its typedefs as a template to the second class like so (pseudo):

```
template<Cluster clusterX, Cluster clusterY>
class Curve
{
    Curve(Axis<clusterX::PhyType> xAxis, Axis<clusterY::PhyType> yAxis)
    {}
};
```

**I need a C++98 solution.**

Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: Also, does [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) make a difference by any chance?

Comment: It says `Cluster is not a type` when trying to compile. I will have a look at it, thank you.

Comment: TL;DR you need `Axis<typename clusterX::PhyType> xAxis`

Comment: Still says that Cluster and Axis is not a type and that the template argument 1 is invalid if I add the typename keyword @NathanOliver

Comment: Hold on, do you actually want non template types or did you mean to have `template<class ClusterX, class ClusterY> class Curve`